# В чем ошибка кода получения полного списка поддерживаемых кодировок и их псевдонимов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Объясните пожалуйста в чем ошибка данном коде

```
# coding: utf-8 -*-
import encodings.aliases
arr = encodings.aliases.aliases
keys = list( arr. keys () )
keys.sort()
for key in keys:
    print("%s => %s” % (key, arr[key]))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте код текстом в вопрос (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: Редактировал, спасибо за замечание)

Comment: кавычки разные (так скопипастили код).

Comment: @J.Jones, спасибо, но добавьте туда еще и ту ошибку

Comment: Где строка print?

Comment: @J.Jones, верно.

Comment: Не, все равно в импорте ошибку выбивает

Comment: С кавычками проблемы, вот правильно: `print("%s => %s" % (key, arr[key]))`

Comment: Не, все та же ошибка напротив импорта

Comment: @J.Jones, у меня все заработало после исправления кавычек. Код после этого работает: https://onlinegdb.com/ryW7h0_LU Возможно, вы что-то не так делаете :)

Comment: Вы в среде 3.6.4 прогоняете его?

Comment: # coding: utf-8 -*-
import encodings.aliases
arr = encodings.aliases.aliases
keys = list( arr.keys () )
keys.sort()
for key in keys:
    print("%s => %s" % (key, arr[key]))

Comment: Переводы строк DOS? (`\r\n` вместо `\n`)

Comment: @gil9red, все работает, спасибо.